# How to decrease time using interval

Tags: reactjs

I have props.time as an integer number (like 1500), I have managed to transfer it into hours, minutes, seconds, but I'm not familiar with Interval to changing state. I rip the hours minutes seconds part out for easier to look, so I have left is this piece of code, why when I use setTimer(time-1), it's just stuck at 1499 (given 1500 as example time), I'm practicing using functional component but I don't understand how it works, thanks.

```
export default function Clock (props){
const {time} = props;
const [timer, setTimer] = useState(time)

useEffect( ()=> {
    secondsToTime(timer)
},[timer])

setInterval(()=>{
        setTimer(time-1)
    }, 1000)
```

Comment: `setInterval` at the top-level inside the component will set a separate interval _every_ time your component re-renders. Put it inside the `useEffect` hook and use the previous state to update the state: `setTimer(currentTime => currentTime - 1)`. Also make sure to use the cleanup function of the `useEffect` hook to clear the interval.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I'll give it a try :D

Answer (score 0):

Every time setInterval is changing, Make sure you clear the interval on destroy. Otherwise, it'll keep on running.

Try like this.

```
export default function Clock (props){
const {time} = props;
const [timer, setTimer] = useState(time)

useEffect( ()=> {
    const t = time-1;
    const interval = setInterval(()=>{
      setTimer(t);
      secondsToTime(t);
    }, 1000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval);
},[]);
```

Comment: I do this but the result gets me to display NaN, the secondsToTime is the format I use to convert it into hours, minutes, and seconds that I mentioned I rip it out for easier to look.